# phraseto_tsquery in PostgreSQL 9.5x or just from 9.6x?

Tags: postgresql

I'm finding references in the 9.5 manual to phraseto_tsquery
https://postgrespro.com/docs/postgrespro/9.5/textsearch-controls

But if I use it in my query it gives me this error:

> No function matches the given name and argument types.

```
SELECT phraseto_tsquery('english', 'The Fat Rats');
```

Was this function not added with 9.5 as intended or is it likely there's some other problem on my side. Running 9.5.4 of the database currently. Anyone that can confirm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking; took the step to install postgresql 9.6beta4 and I'm no longer receiving the error message. In other words phraseto_tsquery seems to only be fully supporting in the current 9.6 beta and upcoming full release.